# Why does ts function return a different type without strict mode?

Tags: typescript, union

sorry for my English, could you please explain to me why without strict mode the function returns a different type?

```js
type Nullable<T> = T | null | undefined;

export const prepareFormDataForApi = <T extends Nullable<IUser>>(data: IFormData, user: T) => {
 return {
   ...data,
   ...(user ? { id: user.id } : data.email ? { isEmailVerified: true } : { isPhoneVerified: true })
 } as T extends IUser ? IUpdateUserRequest : ICreateUserRequest
}

// in that case user is Nullable<IUser> and preparedData type is IUpdateUserRequest, with strict mode type is ICreateUserRequest | IUpdateUserRequest
const preparedData = prepareFormDataForApi(data, user) 

// in that case without strict mode preparedData type is ICreateUserRequest | IUpdateUserRequest with strict mode ICreateUserRequest
const preparedData = prepareFormDataForApi(data, null)
```

I can't figure out what to do if I want a strict mode type result but without strict mode

Comment: [mre] please. Lots of definitions we don't have so it's harder to help. But I believe you wanted `[T] extends [User] ? ... : ...` to disable distribution with strict mode enabled (you should always have strict mode enabled). Let me know if that helps.